# Game server - high latency

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, minecraft

I'm trying to host a Spigot Minecraft 1.12.2 Server using Ubuntu, The server has been properly set up and is working properly, The ping however isn't really great, I am playing from India and the server VM instance region has been set to Germany-Frankfurt, I should be getting anywhere between 130-200ms latency but It's always above 300 or even 1000 at times, I did tracert using windows CMD terminal and the packets seem to go to U.S.A first and then to Germany, I asked several of my friends to ping the server and they all get the same result. How can I fix this? Is there any way to route packets straight to Germany Instead of going to the U.S first?

Made a new Instance in Mumbai Region, India, which is where I live, I'm getting 3 Ping while on the server select menu, but upon joining it jumps to 200.

I expect around 130-160 ping, which is what I get on other servers on that region, Other players who live near Germany are getting high pings, I can't make this server public with a major issue like this.

Comment: Update :- I created a proxy server using GCP in Mumbai which forwards my connection to the Europe server and my connection is much better and very playable, sadly this isn't the case for players from Pakistan and other nearby regions, any fix is appreciated! :D

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the network map on this page: https://cloud.google.com/about/locations/#network-tab

As you can see, Google's network is not connected between Europe and India - therefore traffic has to take a detour around the other side of the world through Asia and the US.

Within a region, so from Germany to Germany and from India to India, you should however achieve low latency.

Comment: Ah, I see, so there's no way I can somehow route the connection for better ping?

Comment: You can try using the standard network tier: https://cloud.google.com/network-tiers/ This will however likely make latency more unpredictable as it then depends on the client/player's ISP and how they are connected globally as traffic will no longer be routed over Google's global backbone.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're experiencing this issue due to instance's machine type and CPU's count.

As stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/5-steps-to-better-gcp-network-performance?hl=ml):

"Outbound or egress traffic from a virtual machine is subject to maximum network egress throughput caps. These caps are dependent on the number of vCPUs that a virtual machine instance has. Each core is subject to a 2 Gbits/second (Gbps) cap for peak performance. Each additional core increases the network cap, up to a theoretical maximum of 16 Gbps for each virtual machine".

Having so little information about your setup i cannot help you further unfortunately.

Please provide more information about your setup and your customer's needs.

For example, who will your customers be? From which country? Is this the reason why you're using an European region for your services while you live in India?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your interest in my issue, at the time of writing my original post, I was using an 8 core Skylake machine with 15 gb of ram for hosting, my "customers" are players around the world who can connect to my server and enjoy playing there, I chose Europe as it's an ideal location to connect players from Asia, Europe and USA. As Europe is pretty much in the middle, it provides optimal ping to Asia players.